# sas infile .xls (2007 excel file) with namerow and startrow

Tags: import, sas

I would like to import `.xls` file using `proc import`. While i only need part of the range (A10:O47)of one of the spreadsheet ("CC"). And the header local at range (A9:O9). I am using ms excel 2007.

```
proc import
    out = work.testing
    datafile = "C:\User\Yin\Desktop\Book.xls"
    dbms = excelcs replace;
    sheet = "CC";
    /*range = "A10:O47";*/
    namerow = 9;
    startrow = 10;
run;
```

There is error msg in the log: for namerow =9;

```
28   proc import
29       out = work.testing
30       datafile = "C:\User\Yin\Desktop\Book.xls"
31       dbms = excelcs replace;
NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
32       sheet = "CC";
33       /*range = "A10:O47";*/
34       namerow = 9;
         -------
         180
35       startrow = 10;
         --------
         180
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.

36   run;
```

thanks.

Comment: What is the question? What happens when you run your code? Why is it not working? Please update your question to help people give you the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, can you tell which statement the error message refers to?

Comment: the line namerow = 9; and startrow = 10;

Comment: Why are you using `EXCELCS`?

Comment: i m using sas9.3. indeed i just follow others code for dbms statement. or i shd use excel2007?

Comment: Try this, http://support.sas.com/kb/5/444.html, but use `GETNAMES=YES` and specify the range accordingly.

Comment: When i switch excelcs to excel2000

ERROR: Connect: Class not registered
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65580/discussion-between-mjsqu-and-user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation, "Available only for DBMS=XLS for backward compatibility"

Appears these options aren't available with excelcs.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003103761.htm

Comment: i have another issue to proc import for xlsm data.

I tried dbms = excel, while there is error about CLI error.